# How to retrieve part of embedded document in mongodb comparing with array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to get specific questions corresponding to arr values matching question No. I tried $where,$in $projection but not working.here the in operator gives only one question i.e question No 1 means it finds for question No 1 in arr and when finds it returns only that but I want questions corresponding to other values in array to. Please help.

```
 var arr=["3","1","5","2","4"];
db.exammasters.find({'examid':"1026","questionMaster.questionNo":{$in:["3","1","5","2","4"]}},{_id: 0, questionMaster: {$elemMatch:{questionNo:{$in:["3","1","5","2","4"]}}},'questionMaster.answer':0})
```

Here is my document

```
{

    "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000046",
    "examid": "1026",
    "name": "C++",
    "description": "C++ exam",
    "questionLimit": 5,
    "examDuration": 5,
    "__v": 0,
    "questionMaster": [
      {
        "questionNo": "1",
        "questionText": "Is bool a fundamental datatype in C++?",
        "answer": "5149532885f5543cb3dc7865c1b41b6a",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200007a",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "Yes",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200007e"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "No, it is a typedef of unsigned char",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200007d"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "No, it is an enum of {false,true}",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200007c"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": "No, it is expanded from macros",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200007b"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "2",
        "questionText": "Find the odd one out:",
        "answer": "6e4fc780d5604c5160f859df934436fb",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000075",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "std::vector<int>",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000079"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": " std::vector<short>",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000078"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": " std::vector<long>",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000077"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": "std::vector<bool>",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000076"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "3",
        "questionText": " What happens when a null pointer is converted into bool?",
        "answer": "4277f0f85e152d162d9433a63f8cf5de",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000070",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "An error is flagged",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000074"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "bool value evaluates to true",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000073"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "bool value evaluates to false",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000072"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": " the statement is ignored",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000071"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "4",
        "questionText": "Which of the following statements are false?",
        "answer": "eaf0eec3ced4c8f4945ac3e1312ba84f",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200006b",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": " bool can have two values and can be used to express logical expressions",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200006f"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "bool cannot be used as the type of the result of the function.",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200006e"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": " bool can be converted into integers implicitly",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200006d"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": " a bool value can be used in arithemetic expressions.",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200006c"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "5",
        "questionText": " For what values of the expression is an if-statement block not executed?",
        "answer": "eaf0eec3ced4c8f4945ac3e1312ba84f",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000068",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": " 0 and all negative values",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200006a"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "0",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000069"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "6",
        "questionText": "A pointer is",
        "answer": "6e4fc780d5604c5160f859df934436fb",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000063",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "A keyword used to create variables",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000067"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "A variable that stores address of an instruction",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000066"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "A variable that stores address of other variable",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000065"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": "All of the above",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000064"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "7",
        "questionText": "Which of the two operators ++ and — work for the bool datatype in C++?",
        "answer": "eaf0eec3ced4c8f4945ac3e1312ba84f",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200005e",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "None",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000062"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "++",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000061"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "--",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000060"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": "both",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200005f"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "8",
        "questionText": " The size_t integer type in C++ is?",
        "answer": "4277f0f85e152d162d9433a63f8cf5de",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200005a",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "Unsigned integer of at least 64 bits",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200005d"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "Signed integer of at least 16 bits",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200005c"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "Unsigned integer of at least 16 bits",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200005b"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "9",
        "questionText": " Which of these expressions will return true if the input integer v is a power of two?",
        "answer": "4277f0f85e152d162d9433a63f8cf5de",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000056",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": " (v | (v + 1)) == 0;",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000059"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "(v | (v – 1)) == 0;",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000058"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "(v & (v – 1)) == 0;",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000057"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "10",
        "questionText": "How does a sequence of objects are accessed in c++?",
        "answer": "4277f0f85e152d162d9433a63f8cf5de",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000051",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "Iterators",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000055"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "Pointers",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000054"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "Both a & b",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000053"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": " None of the mentioned",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000052"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "11",
        "questionText": "How many parameters are present in mismatch method in non-sequence modifying algorithm?",
        "answer": "6e4fc780d5604c5160f859df934436fb",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200004c",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "1",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000050"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "2",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200004f"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "3",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200004e"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": "4",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200004d"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "questionNo": "12",
        "questionText": "What will happen in ‘all_of’ method if the range is empty?",
        "answer": "5149532885f5543cb3dc7865c1b41b6a",
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000047",
        "Options": [
          {
            "optionNo": "1",
            "optionText": "Return true",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200004b"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "2",
            "optionText": "Return false",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200004a"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "3",
            "optionText": "Return nothing",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000049"
          },
          {
            "optionNo": "4",
            "optionText": "None of the mentioned",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000048"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "instructionsDetails": [
      {
        "_id": "5649e095b945ebd41200007f",
        "Instructions": [
          {
            "instructionNo": "1",
            "instruction": "This is C++ Exam Quiz Conducted by Esko",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000081"
          },
          {
            "instructionNo": "2",
            "instruction": "Follow Rules and regulations",
            "_id": "5649e095b945ebd412000080"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you can use aggregation for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From version 3.2 you can use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.2-reference/#exp._S_filter) operator to return an array with only those elements that match your condition.

```js
var myArray = [ "3", "1", "5", "2", "4" ];

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
       "examid": "1026",
       "questionMaster.questionNo": { "$in": myArray }
    }}, 
    { "$project": { 
        "name": 1, 
        "examid": 1, 
        "description": 1, 
        "questionLimit": 1,
        "examDuration": 1, 
        "__v": 1, 
        "questionMaster": {
             "$filter": {
                 "input": "$questionMaster", 
                 "as": "question", 
                 "cond": { 
                     "$setIsSubset": [
                         { "$map": {
                             "input": { "$literal": [ "Q" ] }, 
                             "as": "q", 
                             "in": "$$question.questionNo"
                         }}, 
                         myArray
                     ]
                 }
             }
        }
    }}
])
```

---

Before MongoDB 3.2 you need to filter your documents using the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator. The next stage in the pipeline is [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage where you retrieve only document where "questionNo" is in your array using the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) expression. Because you can't use the `$in` operator in the `$cond` you need to use the [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/#exp._S_setIsSubset) operator which returns true if your "questionNo" appear in your array. But the problem is that `$setIsSubset` takes two array so to make it work you need to use the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map) operator. Of course `$map` input must be an expression that resolve to an array and because "questionNo" is not an array you need to use [`$literal`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal) operator.

```js
var myArray = [ "3", "1", "5", "2", "4" ];

db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "examid": "1026",
        "questionMaster.questionNo": { "$in": myArray }
    }},
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$or": [ 
                { "$setIsSubset": [
                    { "$map": {
                        "input": { "$literal": [ "Q" ] }, 
                        "as": "q", "in": "$questionNo"
                    }},  
                    myArray
                ] }, 
                { "$not": "$questionNo" } 
            ]}, 
            "$$DESCEND", 
            "$$PRUNE" 
        ]
    }}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation framework for this to work. Find query wont help you with this. A sample aggregation query is shown below:

```
db.exammasters.aggregate(
  {$match: {examid:"1026"}},
  {$unwind: "$questionMaster"},
  {$match: {"questionMaster.questionNo": {$in : arr}}},
)
```

Comment: This is inefficient there's better way to do this.